# RegEx to extract first XML element name with optional namespace prefix

Tags: regex, xml

I have to extract with regEx first element name in the xml (ignoring optional namespace prefix.

Here is the sample XML1:

```
<ns1:Monkey xmlns="http://myurlisrighthereheremonkey.com/monkeynamespace">
 <foodType>
  <vegtables>
   <carrots>1</carrots>
  </vegtables>
 <foodType>   
</ns1:Monkey>
```

And here is similar XML that is without namespace, XML2:

```
 <Monkey xmlns="http://myurlisrighthereheremonkey.com/monkeynamespace">
 <foodType>
  <vegtables>
   <carrots>1</carrots>
  </vegtables>
 <foodType>   
</Monkey>
```

I need a regEx that will return me "Monkey" for either XML1 or XML2

So far I tried [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/xZ4eB0/2) this regEx <(\w+:)(\w+) that works for XML1 .... but I don't know how to make it work for XML2

Comment: `<(\w+:)?(\w+)(?=\s*xmlns="http://myurlisrighthereheremonkey\.com/monkeynamespace")` or `^\s*<(\w+:)?(\w+)`, but why regex?

Comment: Thank you! That helps! The code I've got can't use xml parsing.... all I need is to check what "xml type" is it based on the element name. Please add it as an answer, so I can rate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems to be a one-time job and you really do not have access to XML parser, you can use either of the 2 regexps (that will work only for the XML files like you provided as samples):

```
<(\w+:)?(\w+)(?=\s*xmlns="http://myurlisrighthereheremonkey\.com/monkeynamespace")
```

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/xZ4eB0/4)

Or (if you check the whole single file contents with the regex):

```
^\s*<(\w+:)?(\w+)
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/xZ4eB0/3)

The main changes are 2:

- `(\w+:)?` - adding `?` modifier makes the first capturing group optional
- `^\s*` makes the regex match at the beginning of the string (guess you do not have XML declaration there), or `(?=\s*xmlns="http://myurlisrighthereheremonkey.com/monkeynamespace")` look-ahead forcing the match only if followed by optional spaces and literal `xmlns="http://myurlisrighthereheremonkey.com/monkeynamespace"`.

However, you really need to think about changing to code supporting XML parsing, it will make your life and lives of those who will be in charge of maintaining code easier.